# Boost Signals of mobile network

Tags: signal

This may sound over ambitious and silly but I think I should just ask. Lets assume a college campus (I mean a whole campus with buildings, gardens and workshops and stuff). I am thinking around 17 Acres of land. The signal of cellular phones is full just outside the campus, but just as you cross the first building you lose it totally. And then throughout the core of the campus, you don't have any signal at all.

Now how can I do a survey of such a situation for parameters like signal strength, causes of signal drop, places where I get a much better signal etc. There has to be some methodology to do it scientifically. What equipment will I have to use, are there any pre-existing DIY designs for these?

Also once I workout the cause of the signal drop, how can I boost it. Are there any signal booster for cellular network? I am thinking DIY type, something I would build myself and learning a lot of things in the process.

Comment: When i saw the title of your question I thought of these:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/signals.html ...

Comment: Practically: you may not have cell phone coverage, but you probably have lots of Wi-Fi coverage, so get a Skype/GV/SIP account and do internet calling.  :)

Answer (score 4):

What phone do you have?

If it's a smart phone, chances are there is a free app that can display RSSI (signal strength). You can use this number to make a map. You'll find that buildings and trees pose the most interference, and the higher you are the better the signal. You can even come up with a 3d map if you are ambitious :) Just use a smartphone to map the RSSI or SNR.

To boost the signal, the easiest approach is to attach a high gain antenna. A Yagi or even a parabolic dish antenna if you want to get the ladies' attention. :)

Comment: I like the idea of attaching that antenna, I should look into that.

Comment: How would you attach an antenna to a mobile if it does not have the RF extension port?

Comment: You can't, without a lot of work. You will need to know a lot about RF.

Comment: On the board there is usually a circular pad that looks like a target that is also the spot where you would connect your own antenna You could attach a small pigtail (see wrt54g pigtail) . On some devices, like my Motorola Droid there is a micro SMA connector. I'm not sure if it's for the phone or GPS receiver. I've seem similar sockets in many, if not all phones I've had in the past.  I leave that research up to the question asker :)

Comment: Another idea, something I wanted to build a while ago, is a parabolic dish and position the phone's antenna right at the focal point. It would require some hardware but if you use hands free, it could be pretty sweet :)

Comment: @brad I like your idea, building the parabolic dish will be a pain, but that would really sweeten the deal with focus locationing to a desired point

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't want to build the dish from scratch. Maybe there's a surplus dish out there. How about a circular polarized Yagi? Check out "wiFi shootouts". You might also just make a yagi or Helical antenna with your phone being installed into the focal point where the driver element would go..?

Comment: It could work, but the elements will be pretty close together. If you go for high gain, the beamwidth will be pretty narrow, too. You'll want a tripod at that point. Which would look ridiculous. And bulky. On the plus side, you'd get cell service where nobody else does...

Comment: @jesse well put. There's definitely something to be said for doing something totally ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

You will need some rather expensive equipment to perform those measurements, it's best left to the professionals. Boosting the signal as you propose isn't feasible and would be illegal, anyway.

Comment: Why would that be illegal? I am just receiving a signal and boosting it, essentially just repeating it with more power. How is that illegal?

Comment: You need a license to transmit a signal on the mobile phone band, which you won't get.

Comment: ok I should have guessed that. Was a bit sleepy while writing that comment

Answer (score 3):

As has already been said, transmitting within the mobile phone bands would be illegal and will almost certainly make matters worse with your signal interfering with the legitimate signal.

Some of the mobile phone companies (Vodaphone for example) will sell you an internet connected home base station that can allow your mobile phone to "connect" to their network using VOIP if you have no coverage at your home address.

Perhaps you should take this up with the mobile network concerned and they could ask the college for permission to place a repeater on site.  On the other hand the college authorities may be quite pleased that there is no coverage over the campus as it prevents all sorts of disruption to lectures from student phones ringing.

Comment: On the *other* other hand, the college authorities may be quite dismayed that there is no coverage over the campus, because it will make the college less attractive to incoming students, prevent emergency calls, and make it harder for students to connect.

Comment: Well the college I am talking about is sort of a all-you-can do college. It allows for total freedom in doing you work and there are no lectures as such.(Also its the best of the brand).

Answer (score 0):

There is a device called signal meters which help you measure the signals at different places. You can buy or rent those at the store which sell signal boosters like wilson amplifiers and signal boosters. 
try this link https://www.wilsonamplifiers.com/frequently-asked-questions/
it will give you the results in dB readings. you just have to be there at the place where you wanna measure it. This is an easy way to measure signals in numbers. However, there is an other method by downloading an app. Try searching the app, I can't recall the name of the app right now.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Good answer, but many years too late to help the OP. Also some of this equipment is upwards of $1,000 USD.